If the rational number $\frac{a}{b}$ is an integer, do we have $\frac{a}{b} \equiv ab^{-1}$ mod $p$?
Let $p$ be a prime number. In what follows, $\equiv$ means equivalence modulo $p$. If $b$ is an integer that is not a multiple of $p$, it has two multiplicative inverses:

its reciprocal $\frac{1}{b}$ in the field $\mathbb Q$.
its inverse $b^{-1}$ in the field ${\mathbb F}_p$, the quotient $\mathbb Z/{p\mathbb Z}$ with its usual addition and multiplication. For example, if $p=7$ and $b=2$, then $b^{-1}=4$ since $2\times 4 \equiv 8 \equiv 1$. $b^{-1}$ exists because of Bezout's Theorem: $p\wedge b=1$ so there exists integers $u$ and $v$ such that $bu+pv=1$. $u$ and $v$ are not unique, but every choices $u_1$ and $u_2$ for $u$ differ by a multiple of $p$, so I will identify $u$ and $b^{-1}$ from now on.

Now, consider a fraction $c=\frac{a}{b}$, where $a$ is an integer. If $c$ turns out to be an integer, is it true that $c\equiv ab^{-1}$?
(For context, the question came up when a student asked me a question about the computation of binomial coefficients modulo some prime number. She used that property (badly since she didn't clear the denominator of the binomial coefficient of the multiple of the prime) and I was not sure it was legit. I couldn't find any resource about this online.)

Since I am answering my own question, I will wait a day or two before accepting an answer.

It's not clear what you mean.  If you are defining $\frac 1b\equiv b^{-1}$ then it's a tautology.  Otherwise,  I guess you mean to say that "if you write $\frac ab-ab^{-1}$ as a fraction in least terms, then the numerator is a multiple of $p$."  But it's not true that that fraction is an integer times $p$.

@lulu: I am not defining $\frac{1}{b}=b^{-1}$. These objects are defined at the beginning of the question, the multiplicative inverses of $b$ in $\mathbb Q$ and in $\mathbb F_p$, respectively. I should have mentioned that the latter is the field of integers modulo $p$.

But then what does $\frac ab\equiv ab^{-1}$ mean?  Congruence is only defined in the integers.  If you want to extend the notion to include (some) rationals, you need to say how you are extending it.

@lulu: What he is asking is, if $a=kb$ for integers $a$, $k$, $b$, then is $\left(\frac ab=\right)k\equiv ab^{-1}$?

@ultralegend5385  Oh, you are right. I missed that condition in the header.

Yes, it is indeed true (assuming $b \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$).
Just note that $$\frac{a}{b}\cdot b= a \implies \frac{a}{b}\cdot b\equiv a \pmod p \implies \frac{a}{b} \equiv \frac{a}{b}\cdot b\cdot b^{-1} \equiv a\cdot b^{-1} \pmod p$$ (Where we used the existence of the inverse of $b$ mod $p$)

Saying that $c\equiv ab^{-1}$ means that $c-ab^{-1}$ is a multiple of $p$. But
$$b(c-ab^{-1})=bc-abb^{-1}=a-a(bb^{-1})=a-a(1-pv)=pav$$ so $b(c-ab^{-1})$ is a multiple of $p$. Since $p$ is prime and does not divide $b$, $c-ab^{-1}$ is a multiple of $p$.

Did you mean $-$ where you typed $\equiv$ in the last line?
